# Unable to connect to mysql server at boot time

Tags: mysql, linux, qnx

Client side operating System: Qnx 6.4.0

Server side: Red Hat 6.5

I trying to connect to mysql server at boot time from the following script (at qnx machine).

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /root
io-pkt-v4-hc -di82544 -ptcpip
ifconfig en0 192.168.4.122 netmask 255.255.0.0
slay qconn
qconn
dumper -n
inetd
devc-pty
if_up -p en0
./mysql_connect
```

Source code of mysql_connect

```
MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
const char *database = "PRC_OPT";
unsigned int conn_timeout = 5;


      conn = mysql_init(NULL);
      Wprintf(Terminal2,"MySQL Tables connection = %p:\n", conn);
      mysql_options(conn, MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, &conn_timeout);
       /* Connect to database */
       if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, DATABASE_IPADDRESS,
             USER, PASSWORD, database, DATABASE_PORT, NULL, 0)) {
          Wprintf(Terminal2, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          mysql_close(conn);
          return;
       }
       /* send SQL query */
       if (mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM ADRLIS WHERE PM='TKPRC' AND NUMTS=1;")) {
          Wprintf(Terminal2, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          return;
       }
       res = mysql_use_result(conn);

       /* close connection */
       mysql_free_result(res);
       mysql_close(conn);
```

As result I have a following error at **mysql_real_connect**

***Can't connect to MySql server on 'ip address' (4)***
but then .............when I invoke ./mysql_connect (at second time from bash command line) all works correctly.

At first time I was thinking that iptables rejected my connection packets, but this situation is repeated even so I do ***service iptables stop***.

I have invoked tcpdump at server side and have following

```
14:06:15.402347 IP 192.168.4.122.65534 > prc.mysql: Flags [S], seq 33833343, win 32768, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 0,sackOK,nop,nop,nop,nop,TS val 0 ecr 0], length 0
    0x0000:  5254 00b2 fdb1 0023 6b01 13d8 0800 4500  RT.....#k.....E.
    0x0010:  0040 ed1b 4000 4006 c309 c0a8 047a c0a8  .@..@.@......z..
    0x0020:  04c8 fffe 0cea 0204 417f 0000 0000 b002  ........A.......
    0x0030:  8000 db01 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0300 0402  ................
    0x0040:  0101 0101 080a 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
14:06:15.403234 IP prc.mysql > 192.168.4.122.65534: Flags [S.], seq 4145356488, ack 33833344, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 703030136 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  0023 6b01 13d8 5254 00b2 fdb1 0800 4500  .#k...RT......E.
    0x0010:  003c 0000 4000 4006 b029 c0a8 04c8 c0a8  .<..@.@..)......
    0x0020:  047a 0cea fffe f715 1ec8 0204 4180 a012  .z..........A...
    0x0030:  3890 9122 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a 29e7  8.."..........).
    0x0040:  6378 0000 0000 0103 0307                 cx........
14:06:15.403451 IP 192.168.4.122.65534 > prc.mysql: Flags [R], seq 33833344, win 0, length 0
    0x0000:  5254 00b2 fdb1 0023 6b01 13d8 0800 4500  RT.....#k.....E.
    0x0010:  0028 ed1c 0000 4006 0321 c0a8 047a c0a8  .(....@..!...z..
    0x0020:  04c8 fffe 0cea 0204 4180 0000 0000 5004  ........A.....P.
    0x0030:  0000 d4e0 0000 0000 0000 0000            ............
```

As we can see the server reset tcp connection from client. If we try to invoke second time from the bash command line tcp connection is established successfully and then we can work with database without any problems

```
14:18:09.068632 IP 192.168.4.122.65533 > 192.168.4.200.3306: Flags [S], seq 917705451, win 32768, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 0,sackOK,nop,nop,nop,nop,TS val 0 ecr 0], length 0
    0x0000:  5254 00b2 fdb1 0023 6b01 13d8 0800 4500  RT.....#k.....E.
    0x0010:  0040 f115 4000 4006 bf0f c0a8 047a c0a8  .@..@.@......z..
    0x0020:  04c8 fffd 0cea 36b3 12eb 0000 0000 b002  ......6.........
    0x0030:  8000 d4e7 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0300 0402  ................
    0x0040:  0101 0101 080a 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
14:18:09.068681 IP 192.168.4.200.3306 > 192.168.4.122.65533: Flags [S.], seq 4004872844, ack 917705452, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 703743802 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  0023 6b01 13d8 5254 00b2 fdb1 0800 4500  .#k...RT......E.
    0x0010:  003c 0000 4000 4006 b029 c0a8 04c8 c0a8  .<..@.@..)......
    0x0020:  047a 0cea fffd eeb5 828c 36b3 12ec a012  .z........6.....
    0x0030:  3890 4bd7 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a 29f2  8.K...........).
    0x0040:  473a 0000 0000 0103 0307                 G:........
14:18:09.068920 IP 192.168.4.122.65533 > 192.168.4.200.3306: Flags [.], ack 1, win 33580, options [nop,nop,TS val 0 ecr 703743802], length 0
    0x0000:  5254 00b2 fdb1 0023 6b01 13d8 0800 4500  RT.....#k.....E.
    0x0010:  0034 f116 4000 4006 bf1a c0a8 047a c0a8  .4..@.@......z..
    0x0020:  04c8 fffd 0cea 36b3 12ec eeb5 828d 8010  ......6.........
    0x0030:  832c 3007 0000 0101 080a 0000 0000 29f2  .,0...........).
    0x0040:  473a                                     G:
```

What is the difference between those two starts??? Why the first connection is rejected???

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Comment: @Daniel from the /etc/rc.d/rc.local

Comment: Your rc.local is strange to me. It is not common to start the network driver from there. Usually the drivers are started by enum-devices app (called from rc.devices), and those scripts are alredy set in a basic distribution, so you dont need to touch it. For the network configuration,  the usual is to use the /etc/net.cfg (which will be used by the netmanager (called from enum-devices). In the rc.local you should put only specific applications you want to start. In your case, the inetd and the mysql_connect. Also, provide the full path for those apps

Comment: @Daniel Qnx has capability to build your own image of OS for more rapid start. This script starts at last time in the bootstrap sequence. Why you say about full path???  We see that mysql_connect app is started at boot time (see first tcpdump output) , but mysql server reject this attempt.  Maybe something in the ports at client side??? Please see, at first time 65534 port is used but at second time - 65533............